# Configuring instagram-node-lib with subscriptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, instagram

I am looking to do realtime updates on a certain hashtag and have the picture print on the screen. I am having problems setting up my node.js server using the instagram-node-lib module. But I am still receiving a error when running the file (node server.js);

https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib

here is my implementation (server.js using express 3.5.1):

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
var Instagram = require('instagram-node-lib');
var http = require('http');
var request = ('request');
var intervalID;

var pub = __dirname + '/public',
    view = __dirname + '/views';

var clientID = '*****',
    clientSecret = '*****';

Instagram.set('client_id', clientID);
Instagram.set('client_secret', clientSecret);
Instagram.set('callback_url', 'http://my_url.com/callback');
Instagram.set('redirect_uri', 'http://my_url.com');
Instagram.set('maxSockets', 10);

Instagram.subscriptions.subscribe({
  object: 'tag',
  object_id: 'lol',
  aspect: 'media',
  callback_url: 'http://my_url.com/callback',
  type: 'subscription',
  id: '3'
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(pub));
    app.use(express.static(view));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res){
  Instagram.subscriptions.handshake(req, res);
});

app.post('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    // Grab the hashtag "tag.object_id"
    // concatenate to the url and send as a argument to the client side
    data.forEach(function(tag) {
      var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag.object_id + '/media/recent?client_id=******';
      sendMessage(url);

    });
    res.end();
});

console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

All seems well but when running the command (node server.js) I get:

```
   info  - socket.io started
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Listening on port 3000
APISubscriptionError occurred: Invalid response in _request
```

(I also have socket.io stuff in there but I left that out to focus on the problem.)

The APISubscriptionError is directly correlated with the amount of subscriptions I try and do. In this case only the one for the tag "lol" is accounted for. I just would like to run smoothly without this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out my problem and it was unrelated to the Instagram-node-lib (which is a sick library btw). I needed to define all my urls as http://MY_URL.com:3000 because I am running on port 3000. This was creating a conflict when trying to subscribe in my callback url. To make it so that you do not need to use the :3000 suffix it seems as if I will need to create a proxy through nginx for port 80 to run node through.